Balance calculation problem with Foreign Exchange in Mysql
I am trying to make a current balance system for pre-accounting in mysql. I create receipts in different currencies and collect payments in different currencies. My main currency is Turkish Lira (TRY). The amount field in the table below is the amount of the foreign currency itself. I am trying to make my calculations using dovizKarsiligiTl.
yes I missed it
Original table



id
meblag
dovizKuru
dovizKarsiligi
dovizID




452
-60
32,31
1938,63
2


455
100
35,14
3514
3


456
-300
1
300
1






dovizID
name




1
TRY


2
USD


3
EURO



SET @TRY_balance := 0;
SET @USD_balance := 0;
SET @EUR_balance := 0;




id
amount
foreignExchangeEquivalentTl
exchange rate
dovizID
TRY_balance
USD_balance
EUR_balance




452
-60
1938.63
32.31
2
0
1938.6
0


455
100
3514.00
35.14
3
0
1938.6
3514


456
-300
300
1
1
-300
1938.6
3514



In the table above, the TRY_BAKİYE, USD_BAKİYE, EUR_BAKİYE fields are virtual, that is, they can change depending on the transaction we perform in each row.
The table above is now my raw table and my balance fields are incorrect according to my query result.

In line 1, I owe 1938.6 TL, equivalent to -60 dollars.
In the 2nd line, I paid 3514 TL for 100 euros, so according to the balance status of the 2nd line, my debt should have been completed and 1575.4 TL should have become a creditor.
In the 3rd line, I owed 300 TL in return for -300 TL, and since I was credited with 1575.4 TL in the 2nd line, I should have become a creditor of 1275.4 TL. Accordingly, the following table should be formed. However, I cannot find the query that will create this table.




id
amount
exchange rate
dovizID
TRY_balance
USD_balance
EUR_balance




452
-60
32.31
2
0
1938.6
0


455
100
35.14
3
0
0
1575.4


456
-300
1
1
0
0
1275.4



The data here is not fixed but variable. Payment or debt status can be understood from the -+ value in the amount. A positive TL value is kept as the foreign currency equivalent in each line.
We could not reproduce this query in the other forum,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78414788/balance-calculation-problem-with-foreign-exchange-in-mysql



the query is the same, show us the query you got so that we can fix it

Hello nbk, I haven't made any progress. I want to make a running balance system like the 1st picture. You had prepared sample codes before. I opened a topic here so that maybe I could reach someone else.

yes i understand that but i told you such a list must be done in an application, to do it in sl will not get pretty

I need this way now, otherwise errors will occur in accounting. Statement and total balance are incorrect. I am sending pictures according to the query you suggested last. I mark the error on the picture

also the values differ from your table you given, you need to prodie the result that fit the datat and please don't post images

Is the data not clear enough?

no the result table(image has a date, which is missing and the numbers differ, the tables must contain all columns  that result set has or can be calculated

The table structure is as in the link. Can we get the result we want on the table?
[link]https://dbfiddle.uk/JVZazbh-

Without seeing the wanted end result with the original data, i made some adjustments, so that you can see how you can do your endreuslt
The CTE gathers all the needed data, that we need to achieve our endresult
The are of course, columns missing,
WITH CTE AS (SELECT 
  `id`, `meblag`
  , `dovizKuru`, `dovizID`,
  '₺' as try,
  CASE WHEN dovizID =1 THEN
  SUM(CASE WHEN dovizID =1 THEN  `meblag` * `dovizKuru` ELSE 0  END) OVER (ORDER BY `id`) ELSE 0 ENd  as  `TRY_balance`,
  '$' as USD,
   CASE WHEN dovizID =2 THEN SUM(CASE WHEN dovizID =2 THEN  `meblag` * `dovizKuru` ELSE 0 END ) OVER (ORDER BY `id`) ELSE 0 ENd AS `USD_balance`,
  '€' as EUR,
   CASE WHEN dovizID =3 THEN SUM(CASE WHEN dovizID =3 THEN  `meblag` * `dovizKuru` ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY `id`) ELSE 0 END  AS  `EUR_balance` 
  ,SUM(`meblag` * `dovizKuru`) OVER (ORDER BY `id`) as total_balance,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
  FROM balance)
SELECT
  `id`, `meblag`
  , `dovizKuru`, `dovizID`,
CASE WHEN `meblag` <0 then 'Receipt / Invoice' ELSE 'Payment' END 'Operation Type',
  'someday' as 'date',
  
CONCAT( TRY_balance,' ',  try,'\n', USD_balance,' ',  USD,'\n', EUR_balance,' ',  EUR
  , '\n--------------\n', IF( rn > 1,total_balance,0) ,' ',  try) as 'ALL Information'
  FROM CTE
  




id
meblag
dovizKuru
dovizID
Operation Type
date
ALL Information




452
-60
32,31
2
Receipt / Invoice
someday
0 ₺-1920 $0 €--------------0 ₺


455
100
35,14
3
Payment
someday
0 ₺0 $3500 €--------------1580 ₺


456
-300
1
1
Receipt / Invoice
someday
-300 ₺0 $0 €--------------1280 ₺



fiddle
